# C# Datable grouped by two fields, putting 4 field into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, types, grouping

I have a XLSX file that has 4 columns (id, form name, data, imagepath).  My end goal is to group all these rows into concise groupings based on id and form name with an array of docs per form.

```
|ID        | Form     | Date     | ImagePath    |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | ------------ |
|123       | ABC      | 8/1/2023 | c:/pic1.jpg  |
|123       | DEF      | 8/2/2023 | c:/file1.jpg |
|123       | DEF      | 8/2/2023 | c:/file2.jpg |
|123       | DEF      | 8/2/2023 | c:/file3.jpg |
|456       | GHI      | 8/1/2023 | c:/test1.jpg |
|456       | GHI      | 8/1/2023 | c:/test2.jpg |
```

What I'm try to do is this:

```
|ID        | Form     | Date     | ImagePath    |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | ------------ |
|123       | ABC      | 8/1/2023 | c:/pic1.jpg  |
|123       | DEF      | 8/2/2023 | c:/file1.jpg |
|          |          |          | c:/file2.jpg |
|          |          |          | c:/file3.jpg |
|456       | GHI      | 8/1/2023 | c:/test1.jpg |
|456       |          |          | c:/test2.jpg |
```

Once I get it into that format, I'll then be able to iterate back through them and do some processing for each ID and form.

I've created a class:

```
public string ID {get; set;}
public string Form {get; set;}
public DateTime docDate {get; set;}
public List<string> files {get; set;)
```

Inside my program i've tried:

```
Foreach (DataRow row in caseDT.Rows)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < caseDT.Columns.Count; i++)
   {
      // tried multiple if's
   }
}
```

I imagine this could be done by a linq statement, but haven't had luck with those.

```
var data = caseDT.AsEnumerable();
CaseDoc[] results = data
   .GroupBy(x => new {ID = x.Field<string>("ID"), Form = x.Field<string>("Form")})
   .Select(x => new CaseDoc
    {
       ID = x.key.ID,
       Form = x.key.CaseDoc,
       docDate = // how do I get docdate
       files = // do I do another select here for all the items from image path??
    }
```

While my test sample is small, the overall size of the final XLS will be 9000 rows.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest you create a class that represents a row in your XLSX file. Based on the data you have shared something like this would be close what's needed:

```
 public class Document
 {
     public string Id {get; set;}
     public string Form {get; set;}
     public DateTime DocumentDate {get; set;}
     public string ImagePath {get; set;)
 }
```

Once you read the XLSX file and for each row you have created an instance of the `Document` class, you can proceed with the grouping as below. I assume that you have assigned all parsed rows in a variable called `documents`.

Regarding the groups you are going to create you can either define a class and project each group results in an instance of this class or you can use an anonymous class. Let's assume that you want to go with the first option (this is what I understand from your initial post), defining a class.

```
public class DocumentsGroup
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Form { get; set; }

    // Every attribute of the group that is not in the key you use 
    // to create the group could be defined as a List<T>, where
    // T is the corresponding type  

    public List<DateTime> DocumentsDates { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImagesPaths { get; set; }
}

var result = documents.GroupBy(document => new 
                      {
                          Id = document.Id, 
                          Form = document.Form 
                      })
                      .Select(gr => new DocumentsGroup 
                      {
                          Id = gr.Id,
                          Form = gr.Form,
                          DocumentsDates = gr.Select(item => item.DocumentDate)
                                             .ToList()
                          ImagesPaths = gr.Select(item => item.ImagePath)
                                          .ToList()
                      })
                      .ToList();
```

Note: if you want also `DocumentDate` to be part of the grouping -I'm not sure 100%, if you want this or not-, then a) you just have to change the `DocumentsGroup` -please check the comments there-, & b) include in the key used for the grouping also this property.

Comment: Thanks!! This is what I was looking for.  I changed docdate out of list, since each group of docs would share date, then added it to the key group.  From initial results, this is doing what I need.  Much appreciated!